Compare 2 columns having addresses but in different format in Oracle
Need to compare data in two tables having addresses. Only difference is in one table there is data in abbreviations like St, E, W, Rd etc while in other table the data is like Street, East, West, Road etc.
Example: Need to compare these two address and result as true:
3280 Southeast 19th Avenue
3280 SE 19th Ave

there are entire commercial software packages that do address cleanup/matching; it's not something you're going to get built-in to a database. While you can certainly replace a set of strings, just building up a dictionary of all the possible changes you may have to make is an enormous task. Then again, if your situation truly is limited to just a couple of abbreviations, then define your mapping and loop through a set of replaces.

Re-read Paul's comment.
On the other hand, as you didn't describe what kind of "result" satisfies your needs, have a look at the following example. It calculates similarity between two values; result is percentage.
SQL> with test (id, addr1, addr2) as
  2    (select 1, '3280 Southeast 19th Avenue', '3280 SE 19th Ave'            from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'Frankopanska 23, Zagreb'   , 'Frankop. 23, ZG'             from dual union all
  4     select 3, '2300 Oracle Way Austin, TX', '2300 Oracle WY Austin Texas' from dual union all
  5     select 4, '3280 Northwest 29th Street', '1280 Bingo St'               from dual
  6    )
  7  select id,
  8    utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(addr1, addr2) sim
  9  from test
 10  order by id;

        ID        SIM
---------- ----------
         1         84
         2         87
         3         90
         4         59

SQL>

Let's presume that any result - whose similarity is higher than 80% - is satisfactory, you'd then apply that condition:
<snip>
  7  select id, addr1, addr2
  8  from test
  9  where utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(addr1, addr2) >= 80
 10  order by id;

        ID ADDR1                      ADDR2
---------- -------------------------- ---------------------------
         1 3280 Southeast 19th Avenue 3280 SE 19th Ave
         2 Frankopanska 23, Zagreb    Frankop. 23, ZG
         3 2300 Oracle Way Austin, TX 2300 Oracle WY Austin Texas

SQL>

